# trying to understand xp_cmdShell

Tags: ssms, share, xp-cmdshell, directory-listing

I know how to use xp_cmdshell to get a listing of a local directory.
The statement below gives me a list of cvs files in the dir C:\TEST.
I ran the statement in my **locally installed SSMS**.

```
EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell 'dir C:\TEST\*.csv /b'
```

However,

```
EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell 'dir \\ip-adress\share\folder\*.csv /b'
```

returns a 'No access'.

But running `dir \\ip-adress\share\folder\*.csv /b` in my commandshell does return a listing. Apparantly I as a user have sufficient rights. Then why does xp_cmdShell return a 'access denied' ?

Is xp_cmdSHell unusable with shares or has this to do with the account that issues the command? But if I started SSMS locally, should  the command not run locally under my WIndowsaccount? Same as in commandshell?

Comment: Presumably the service account that SQL Server is using does *not* have access to the remote path. `xp_cmdshell` runs under the credentials of the service account, not the account you are connected as.

Comment: I used a SSIS proxy based on my own credentials but it looks like the machine on which the SQL Server is running, is blocked from accessing that share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a SSIS proxy based on my own credentials but it looks like the machine on which the SQL Server is running, is blocked from accessing that share